# B2C - Custom Policy - Split SignUp and Verification breaks Password Reset

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

I have a custom policy that incorporates the Embedded Password Reset flow as outlined here:  https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset.

Now, I need to split the signup and verification screens so I tried following the sample here:  https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup.

Once I have combined the two custom policies, the Signup and Signin flows work fine.  However clicking on the Reset Password link gives me:  "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Here are the combined policies:

```xml
<BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <!-- Sample: Read only email address to present to the user-->
      <ClaimType Id="readonlyEmail">
        <DisplayName>E-mail Address</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="isForgotPassword">
        <DisplayName>isForgotPassword</DisplayName>
        <DataType>boolean</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>Whether the user has clicked Forgot Password</AdminHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateReadonlyEmailClaim" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readonlyEmail" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>
    <ContentDefinitions>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsigninwithpasswordreset">
        <LoadUri>~/tenant/default/unified.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:2.1.2</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
  </BuildingBlocks>

  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Email Verification</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
      <!--Sample: Email verification only-->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="EmailVerification">
          <DisplayName>Initiate Email Address Verification For Local Account</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary"
                    Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
            <Item Key="language.button_continue">Continue</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <!--Sample: Sign-up self-asserted technical profile without Email verification-->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail">
          <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary"
                    Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
            <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
            <!-- Sample: Remove sign-up email verification -->
            <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">False</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateReadonlyEmailClaim" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <!--Sample: Set input the ReadOnlyEmail claim type to prefilled the email address-->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <!-- Sample: Display the ReadOnlyEmail claim type (instead of email claim type)-->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />

            <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <!-- Sample: Disable session management for sign-up page -->
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="ForgotPassword">
          <DisplayName>Forgot your password?</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isForgotPassword" DefaultValue="true" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/>
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkOverride">ForgotPasswordExchange</Item>
          </Metadata>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>

  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="CustomSignUp">
      <OrchestrationSteps>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsigninwithpasswordreset">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange"/>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange"/>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPasswordExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email"/>
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH"/>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="EmailVerification"/>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ForgotPasswordExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ForgotPassword" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>


        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <JourneyList>
            <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="PasswordReset" />
          </JourneyList>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError"/>
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Show self-asserted page only if the directory does not have the user account already (i.e. we do not have an objectId).
          This can only happen when authentication happened using a social IDP. If local account was created or authentication done
          using ESTS in step 2, then an user account must exist in the directory by this time. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social"/>
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent
          in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId"/>
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- The previous step (SelfAsserted-Social) could have been skipped if there were no attributes to collect
             from the user. So, in that case, create the user in the directory if one does not already exist
             (verified using objectId which would be set from the last step if account was created in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId"/>
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="9" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer"/>

      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb"/>
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>
  <SubJourneys>
      <SubJourney Id="PasswordReset" Type="Call">
        <OrchestrationSteps>
          <!--Sample: Validate user's email address. Run this step only when user resets the password-->
          <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <ClaimsExchanges>
              <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
          </OrchestrationStep>

          <!--Sample: Collect and persist a new password. Run this step only when user resets the password-->
          <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <ClaimsExchanges>
              <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
          </OrchestrationStep>
        </OrchestrationSteps>
      </SubJourney>
    </SubJourneys>
    <RelyingParty>
      <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="CustomSignUp" />
      <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
        <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
        <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        </OutputClaims>
        <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
      </TechnicalProfile>
    </RelyingParty>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

I had to add preconditions to Orchestration step 3

like:

```
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: Exactly, as this step requires an email to function, and you want to skip this step of the user went through the forgotPassword technical profile.