# split sign up and verification breaks password reset custom policy b2c

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have applied what is suggested here
[B2C - Custom Policy - Split SignUp and Verification breaks Password Reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69498425/b2c-custom-policy-split-signup-and-verification-breaks-password-reset)
but still after adding password reset, sign up in combinedsignin fails, this is the error I get 'User journey went into a bad state. Claims exchange with id 'SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange' could not be found in orchestration step '2''
any idea how to fix this?thx

```
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn_Custom">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPasswordExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange_EmailVerification" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="EmailVerification" />
        <ClaimsExchange Id="ForgotPasswordExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ForgotPassword" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange_WithReadOnlyEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

       <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <JourneyList>
        <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="PasswordReset" />
      </JourneyList>
    </OrchestrationStep>



    <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>newUser</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>

        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
        <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
        <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="EmailVerifyOnSignIn" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="EmailVerifyOnSignIn" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
  </OrchestrationSteps>
</UserJourney>
```